# Python merge a random value with a string

Tags: python

I want to make a Random range of IP Address from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.11
using below codes but get wrong result :

```
target = '192.168.0.',random.randint(1,11)
print'Target:',target
```

Result of above code is `Target: ('192.168.0.',7)`
don't show as a one string .

I want to have a result like : `Target : '192.168.0.7'`
Wehre is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say

```
target = '192.168.0.',random.randint(1,11)
```

you are actually creating a tuple and assigning to `target`. You can convert the number to a string with `str` and concatenate it like this

```
target = '192.168.0.' + str(random.randint(1,11))
```

But the preferred way is to use template strings and fill it with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function, like this

```
target = '192.168.0.{}'.format(random.randint(1,11))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do old-school string substitution with the `%` operator.

```
target = '192.168.0.%d' % (random.randint(1,11))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do simple concatenation ,

like ,

```
>>> target = '192.168.0.'
>>> target+str(random.randint(1,11))
'192.168.0.5'
>>>
```

Another example ,

```
>>> target = '192.168.0.'
>>> for i in range(1,11):
          target+str(random.randint(1,11))


'192.168.0.3'
'192.168.0.1'
'192.168.0.2'
'192.168.0.4'
'192.168.0.6'
'192.168.0.7'
'192.168.0.3'
'192.168.0.11'
'192.168.0.5'
'192.168.0.11'
```